# Caracteres especiales en sitio web hecho en cakephp

Tags: html5, cakephp, utf-8, caracteres

Hola estoy modificando un sitio web diseñado en cakephp, pero en un modal para whatsapp algunos caracteres especiales no se ven bien y he intentado hacer algunas cosas y nada me ha funcionado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Seadog">

    <!-- GEOTAG -->
    <meta name="DC.title" content="Velez Lara" />
    <meta name="geo.region" content="CO-ANT" />
    <meta name="geo.placename" content="Medell&iacute;n" />
    <meta name="geo.position" content="6.206279;-75.570182" />
    <meta name="ICBM" content="6.206279, -75.570182" />

    <!-- <meta name="lang" content="es-co" /> -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="google" content="index, follow" />
```

Así estaba originalmente

intento1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Seadog">

    <!-- GEOTAG -->
    <meta name="DC.title" content="Velez Lara" />
    <meta name="geo.region" content="CO-ANT" />
    <meta name="geo.placename" content="Medell&iacute;n" />
    <meta name="geo.position" content="6.206279;-75.570182" />
    <meta name="ICBM" content="6.206279, -75.570182" />

    <!-- <meta name="lang" content="es-co" /> -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="google" content="index, follow" />
```

intento2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Seadog">

    <!-- GEOTAG -->
    <meta name="DC.title" content="Velez Lara" />
    <meta name="geo.region" content="CO-ANT" />
    <meta name="geo.placename" content="Medell&iacute;n" />
    <meta name="geo.position" content="6.206279;-75.570182" />
    <meta name="ICBM" content="6.206279, -75.570182" />

    <!-- <meta name="lang" content="es-co" /> -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="google" content="index, follow" />
```

Este es el modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">¡Tu procedimiento en manos de un especialista!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   Para el Dr. Vélez Lara es muy importante conocer tu caso. Nuestro equipo estará disponible para tí.<br/><br/>

<strong>Horarios de atención:</strong> Lunes a viernes de 8:00 am a 5:00 pm.<br/><br/>

¡Muchas gracias!<br/><br/>


<div class="btn-wpcenter"><a class="btn btn-whatsapp" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=573337890901&text=Hola! Quiero una Cita de Valoración con el Dr. Vélez Lara para (Escribe tu caso puntual)" target="_blank">Escribir mensaje <span class="pl10"><img src="./img/wp2.png" width="21" height="21"/></span></a></div>
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero sin importar que haga el resultado es el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y las BD tiene la siguiente codificación, no se si eso sirva de algo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: definitivamente esta linea de código te debería servir `<meta charset="utf-8">` ahora si lo ves malo probablemente tu IDE esta codificando tus archivos en ANSI, asegúrate de que tu IDE este codificando los archivos en utf-8

Comment: @LPZadkiel yo estoy codificando en sublime text 3, no se si eso tenga que ver

Comment: en el menú de opciones guarda el archivo de esta forma: "File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8"